# How do I sum values from a list in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift5, swiftui-list

I have a list of variable double values in swiftUI. I want to sum them all at the bottom.

In regular swift I would just add up all the textfields/labels. I can access them all directly.

But here I won't know how many they are or how to actually access them specifically.

I can do a list.count for the total number of items. But I would like to sum them.

Can't find any examples.

```
struct ContentView: View {
var food_items : [FoodItem] = []
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List(food_items) {food_item in

            HStack {
                Text(food_item.food_name)
                Text(String(format: "%.2f", food_item.food_measure))
                Text(String(format: "%.2f", food_item.food_calorie))
            }
        }
        Text("Total Calories:")
        Text(String(food_items.count))
    }
}
```

}

Solution

From https://learnappmaking.com/map-reduce-filter-swift-programming/

The map function loops over every item in a collection, and applies an operation to each element in the collection.

The reduce function loops over every item in a collection, and combines them into one value.

```
Text(String(food_items.map{$0.food_calorie}.reduce(0, +)))
```

Comment: how are you displaying the data from your list? An array?

Comment: just threw in the code

Comment: You could try throwing/appending the data into an array, then passing the array into your list.

Comment: I was thinking I would have to iterate the food_items list and then just sum them and save that. Not sure if it would cause problems later when things are added/deleted.

Comment: Total calories: `food_items.map { $0.food_calorie }.reduce(0, +)`

Comment: Perfect. It works. Adding some detail to my post.

Comment: To make sure others can find the solution as well; please put the solution in an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

food_items.map { $0.food_calorie }.reduce(0, +)

Comment: Where did you insert the food_items.map?

Comment: The last line of code instead of the food.count